# Write in file .properties

Tags: android, properties

I am doing an application with android 2.2, i created a file config.properties in the assets folder, i am trying modify the properties with the following code:

```
AssetManager am = this.getResources().getAssets();
Properties pp = new Properties();

InputStream isConfig = am.open("config.properties",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);           
pp.load(isConfig);

pp.setProperty("SHOP_URL", "NEW_SHOP_URL");//This key exists

try {
    pp.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When run the application,throw this error:
java.io.FileNoFoundException: Read-only file system.

I am trying adding permissions to solve this error,but i dont know which add.

Thanks by help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the file path. try using

```
try {
    pp.store(getAssets().openFd("config.properties").createOutputStream(), null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this should fix the path problem.